# как залить пост на wordpress с помощью curl bash

Tags: php, wordpress, bash, post, curl

есть функция стандартная  `wp_insert_post()` 
как можно вставить пост с помощью этой функции через `bash`

```
~$: curl ????
```

и где указать *логин* и *пароль* от **WP**

Comment: https://wp-cli.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно воспользоваться утилитой `WP-CLI`, которую можно вызывать через bash скрипт. В `WP-CLI` пост можно создать при помощи команды:

```
wp post create
```

Более подробно с описанием данной команды вы можете ознакомиться на [официальном сайте](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/create/).